# Fancybox - implementing backward and forward for iFrames

Tags: javascript, iframe, fancybox-2

I'm using Fancybox to display webpages through an iFrame. Those webpages are like a little information network: they're calling each other via links, and the user can circle through them. 
I wanted to implement back et forth buttons: I did it by putting those buttons directly inside the displayed page, and working with the history `(history.go(-1))` : that works, as long as the browser behaves in the way they do with iFrames.
However, there's a problem: if the user clicks on the back button and is on the first page of his navigation, it will bring him back out of the website itself (as, out of the fancy box, it's a one-page website). 
As for security purpose you cannot have access to the history and test it to avoid that, is there a way to find out if the user will get out of the domain if he does a step more? Document.referent doesn't seem to work in the context of Fancybox and iFrames…

Thanks A LOT, I tried many (mainly stupid things), including a javascript session with window.name (see how desperate I am ?) !

Comment: Can you show a simple example on jsfiddle or plunkr.co? You may be able to have the buttons outside of the iFrame and send messages back and forth using the postmessage api

Comment: `if the user click on the back button` ... do you mean, the buttons you implemented inside the iframe? ... or the browser's back button?

Comment: I guess you would need to validate `history.length` inside of each iframe. If `history.length > 1` (most modern browsers return `1` for the first item or the number of URLs in the history list while IE returns `0`) then show your back button (`history.go(-1)`) otherwise hide it (or disable it) so the user can't go back (and outside fancybox)